# Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException:

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
```

I am getting the above error message when i try to deploy a sample web project into Tomcat. The tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1 jar is existing in my local repository.

### pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <server>tomcat</server>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
</plugin>
```

Comment: commons-codec-1.10.jar file is also existing in my local repository.. and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It might be linked to commons-codec.jar missing. Download it from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi.
Then add it project build path. To do that right click the project, click Properties, click "Java Build Path", open "Library" tab, and click "Add External JARs...".

Or if you are using maven add dependency for

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: commons-codec-1.10.jar file is also existing in my local repository.. and still facing the same issue

Comment: try deleting your .m2 repository, users seems to have correct numerous problems doing this